# Python: Read line by line, performing an operation at each end line

Tags: python, file

I've recently picked up Python again after not using it for several years to do some school projects that don't have a specified language requirement. My current project is to create a simple priority queue using a max-heap structure. My current issue is with my input file. For each line of input we are given several tuples consisting of: one string (the data) and one number (the priority).

Ex:

```
(R10, 10), (R20, 20), (R90, 90), (R75, 75), (R35, 35), (R60, 60), (R260, 60), (R360, 60)  
(R15, 15)  
(R50, 50)  
(R275, 75)
```

For each line we need to insert each tuple of information into our priority queue heap and pop and return the highest priority, then repeat for each line.

Ex Output: (what it should be)

```
*insert all into queue* print (R90) *next line*  
*insert into queue* print (R75) *next line*  
*etc*
```

I'm confused on how exactly to get the data into a form I can work with. I've got this currently.

```
with open(fileName) as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        nodes = line.split('), (')
```

and that returns this: (which is currently the closest I've gotten)

```
['(R10, 10', 'R20, 20', 'R90, 90', 'R75, 75', 'R35, 35', 'R60, 60', 'R260, 60', 'R360, 60', 'R210, 10', 'R5, 5', 'R76, 76', 'R80, 80)\n']  
['(R15, 15)\n']  
['(R50, 50)\n']  
['(R275, 75)\n']
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is easiest solved with a regular expression:

```
import re
# This regular expression will match '(<group1>,<group2>)'
# with any whitespace between ',' and <group2> being discarded
tuple_pattern = tuple_pattern = re.compile("\(([^,)]+),\s*([^)]+)\)")

with open(fileName) as f:
    # Find all occurences of the tuple pattern in the file, this gives
    # us an array of tuples where each tuple is (<group1>,<group2>)
    # for each match
    tuples = tuple_pattern.findall(f.read())
```

With your input data this is the result:

```
>>> tuple_pattern.findall("""(R10, 10), (R20, 20), (R90, 90), (R75, 75), (R35, 35), (R60, 60), (R260, 60), (R360, 60)  
... (R15, 15)  
... (R50, 50)  
... (R275, 75)""")
[('R10', '10'), ('R20', '20'), ('R90', '90'), ('R75', '75'), ('R35', '35'), ('R60', '60'), ('R260', '60'), ('R360', '60'), ('R15', '15'), ('R50', '50'), ('R275', '75')]
```

Edit:

If you need to handle each line separately, just do `tuple_pattern.findall(line)` for each line in `file.readlines()`

```
import re
tuple_pattern = re.compile("\(([^,)]+),\s*([^)]+)\)")

with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(tuple_pattern.findall(line))
```

Outputs:

```
[('R10', '10'), ('R20', '20'), ('R90', '90'), ('R75', '75'), ('R35', '35'), ('R60', '60'), ('R260', '60'), ('R360', '60')]
[('R15', '15')]
[('R50', '50')]
[('R275', '75')]
```

Comment: Could you explain what exactly is happening with this code? Learning how exactly it works will be very helpful in the future. Also, this cuts off the first digit of the number; is there a way around that?

Comment: I fixed the regular expression - the + was on the wrong side of the final parenthesis.

Comment: What happens here is that we create a regular expression that matches a tuple and captures the first and second value in it. findall() then applies this pattern as many times as possible to the input string and returns a list of all captured groups of all matches.

Comment: Sorry I was having some issued with the comment tool. I tried to implement the for each line part, but was unable to get it to run successfully, could you show how you would implement that part?

Comment: I've added it to my answer. Be careful when you copy over the regular expression since getting it wrong can have weird effects =)

Comment: Thank you again! This helped me a lot and I think I'm on my way to getting this out of the way.

Comment: You can use ast.literal_eval, https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html, if you want to convert those strings into python tuples.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval('(R10, 10), (R20, 20)')` will throw a ValueError since _R10_ and _R20_ isn't valid Python. He'd have to change his source data to be `'("R10", 10), ("R20", 20)'` for that to work.